# Erc-20 Token Send Transaction

Tags: go-ethereum, myetherwallet, websocket, web3.php

I want some Information about Erc-20 Transactions. I want to transfer Erc-20Token from first wallet to a second wallet, I have Privet Key, But I want to transfer with Api,  So How can I transfer the Erc-20 Tokens?

Comment: you should first know the address of the ERC20 smart contract, then you can do that easily with Metamask in your browser

Comment: But i want to Withdraw On my storage wallet to user wallet , when click user withdraw button ,  I want to use this for exchanger

Answer (score 0):

Install NodeJS.

Run `npm install web3@1.2.1`.

Implement file `send.js`:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");

async function send(value, firstWalletPrivateKey, secondWalletPublicAddress) {
    const web3 = new Web3("https://mainnet.infura.io");
    const options = {
        value   : value,
        gas     : 21000,
        to      : secondWalletPublicAddress,
        gasPrice: await web3.eth.getGasPrice()
    };
    const signedTx  = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, firstWalletPrivateKey);
    const txReceipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(txReceipt, null, 4));
}

send(your_value, your_firstWalletPrivateKey, your_secondWalletPublicAddress);
```

Run `node send.js`.

Comment: Need There Any Different Hosting , or My Regular sharing hosting ?

Comment: @user56799: WHAT?????

Comment: How can i install nodejs. , ?

Comment: @user56799: Don't push it. Search `install nodejs` on Google.